# How do we use easygui load a image

Tags: python, python-3.x, easygui

I can't seem to load a picture I tried this

```
image = "python_and_check_logo.gif"
msg = "Do you like this picture?"
choices = ["Yes","No","No opinion"]
reply = buttonbox(msg, image=image, choices=choices)
```

Can anyone help me load a picture?

Comment: do you have a pic of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just asking, but do you even have that image, if you don't then it wouldn't work also did you import easygui(if you didn't then do it)

Answer (score 1):

you can also try to load another photo instead by using this format

```
image = "photo.gif"
```

Answer (score 1):

Read [Easygui docs](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/api.html?highlight=msgbox#easygui.msgbox) for answers!
I think that you must choose type like this

```
from easygui import buttonbox
image = "Path\\To\\python_and_check_logo.gif"
title = "Choose Your Title"
msg = "Do you like this picture?"
choices = ["Yes","No","No opinion"]
reply = buttonbox(msg=msg, title=title, choices=(choices), image=image)
```